# Unable to login to linux machine

Tags: linux, permissions, login

I can't login to my linux machine. It's giving me the following error:

```
/usr/libexec/gconf-sanity-check-2 exited with status 256
```

I removed all the files in the `/tmp` directory after this issue happened.

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to run a live ubuntu CD , mount the root partition and change the permission of /tmp directory to 1777.
then it will work.

Comment: No, this will not work. He said that he deleted the content of /tmp and not /tmp itself. Even if then the permission has to be 1777!

Comment: mailq: i can read english and already know what he said :) . but this problem Always come because the permission of /tmp are not 777. Let him try and get results.

Comment: I agree he should try, but I also think you should edit your perms to 1777, to make sure it's sticky.

Comment: @Frank your solution got worked, but still i dont know how the permisson of /tmp directory got changed thank you all